# how to tie a list of value with another in R

Tags: r

I am trying to tie a column of variable in my csv file to a list of integers. Here's the short example of my data:

```
     blocks
1.   097XX S BRENNAN AVE
2.   105XX S YATES AVE
3.   105XX S YATES AVE
4.   103XX S CORLISS AVE
5.   097XX S BRENNAN AVE
6.   103XX S CORLISS AVE
```

so by unique(blocks), I actually have 3 unique block names, and I assign them block numbers in integers:

```
     blocks               block_num
1.   097XX S BRENNAN AVE    1
2.   105XX S YATES AVE      2
3.   103XX S CORLISS AVE    3
```

The question is how can i get the original long block list a corresponding column of block numbers, like this :

```
     blocks                 block_num
1.   097XX S BRENNAN AVE    1
2.   105XX S YATES AVE      2
3.   105XX S YATES AVE      2
4.   103XX S CORLISS AVE    3
5.   097XX S BRENNAN AVE    1
6.   103XX S CORLISS AVE    3
```

I have about 2,000 block observations. so I'm looking for a fast way to apply the assigning to the long list.

Thanks !

Comment: You are probably looking for `help("merge")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, I have used the `data.table` package, but you could do the same with a `data.frame`. The core of the solution is matching the block the list of unique blocks using the `match` function.

```
set.seed(1234)
library(data.table)
xmpl <- data.table(block = sample(c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"), 10, TRUE))

xmpl[ , block_num := match(block, unique(block))]
xmpl
#     block block_num
#  1:   aaa         1
#  2:   bbb         2
#  3:   bbb         2
#  4:   bbb         2
#  5:   ccc         3
#  6:   bbb         2
#  7:   aaa         1
#  8:   aaa         1
#  9:   bbb         2
# 10:   bbb         2
```

Just for completeness - the `data.frame` solution is:

```
set.seed(1234)
xmpl <- data.frame(block = sample(c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"), 10, TRUE))
xmpl$block_num <- match(xmpl$block, unique(xmpl$block))
```

Note that `unique` does not reorder, and the alphabetical order given in the first example was purely by chance. The method still holds when the blocks do not happen to fall into alphabetical order.

```
xmpl <- data.table(block = rep(c("bbb", "aaa", "ccc"), 3))
xmpl[ , block_num := match(block, unique(block))]
xmpl
     block block_num
# 1:   bbb         1
# 2:   aaa         2
# 3:   ccc         3
# 4:   bbb         1
# 5:   aaa         2
# 6:   ccc         3
# 7:   bbb         1
# 8:   aaa         2
# 9:   ccc         3
```

Answer (score 3):

A more idiomatic approach in "data.table" would be to use `.GRP`.

Continuing with dayne's sample data:

```
set.seed(1234)
library(data.table)
xmpl <- data.table(block = sample(c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"), 10, TRUE))
xmpl[, block_num := .GRP, by = block][]
#     block block_num
#  1:   aaa         1
#  2:   bbb         2
#  3:   bbb         2
#  4:   bbb         2
#  5:   ccc         3
#  6:   bbb         2
#  7:   aaa         1
#  8:   aaa         1
#  9:   bbb         2
# 10:   bbb         2
```

Comment: Nice -- I completely forgot about .GRP.